# Python Selenium Multiple Webdrivers

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

So I have this python selenium code and I want it to run multiple times at the same time. So when I activate it, it opens multiple webdrivers and execute this script at the same time. How can I do this?

```js
driver.get(base_url)
password_id = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
password = input("Password: ")
password_id.send_keys(password)
password_id.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
email_id1 = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'email'))
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(email_id1)
email_id = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
email_id.send_keys(user_email)
start = time.time()
print(Fore.WHITE + "STATUS:" + Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX + " Email Filled!")
name_id = driver.find_element_by_id('name')
name_id.send_keys(user_name)
print(Fore.WHITE + "STATUS:" + Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX + " Name Filled!")
button_id = driver.find_element_by_id('purchase')
end = time.time()
button_id.click()
print(Fore.WHITE + "STATUS:" + Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + " Processing order...")
sleep(10)
timeresult = end - start
speed = (str(timeresult))
checkout_done = driver.current_url
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried multithreading?
Code below allows me to open two browsers at once (in separate loops) and control them within functions (first_window(), second_window()).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from threading import Thread

def first_window():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")

def second_window():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=first_window).start()
    Thread(target=second_window).start()
```